# What color are Nissa, Worldwaker's lands?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Nissa, Worldwaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383328) turns lands into 4/4 Elemental creatures. My question is...  what color are these tokens? Are they green, the color that the land in question produces, or are they colorless since the card doesn't specify?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally lands are colorless (there is currently only one exception). Nissa does not assign a color to the lands she turns into elementals, so they would remain colorless.

Also worth noting, there are no tokens created. I am not exactly sure what you mean by this. What happens when you use Nissa's ability is that a land *becomes* a 4/4 Elemental creature, while also retaining its previous properties as a land (tapping for mana, having the "Land" type, etc).

Comment: One land isn't colorless by default. The color of a card has nothing to do with its type. That's why I posted my answer.

Comment: @ikegami While that is technically true in the rules, there has never been, and almost certainly never will be, a land with a mana cost.

Comment: If a land had a mana cost, you wouldn't have to pay it as per 202.1b. That doesn't mean that they could not decide to color a land again, like they did with Dryad Arbor. If you Nissa a Dryad Arbor, it's a green elemental.

Comment: @GendoIkari, Correct, but irrelevant. I don't know why you're saying that unless you're trying to imply there has never been or will never be a land that isn't colorless out of the box, but that's clearly false: Dryad Arbor.

Comment: @ikegami I guess the point was that "Lands by default are colorless", while technically untrue and incorrect; is a fair way to explain colors and lands to someone who isn't familiar with the complexities of the actual MTG rules.

Comment: @GendoIkari, Right, figuring out the color of a card isn't commonly required knowledge, so we might as well tell them that color is based on the card's type. ...Oh wait, it is commonly needed knowledge, and as such, telling them it's based on the card type when it's not will cause confusion.

Comment: @ikegami: Lands are default colorless seems safe to say. Lands do not have a casting cost and thus are colorless. Color indicators are rare enough to be considered an exception you have to think about, and any card with a type land and no color indicator would be colorless (since again, lands don't have mana symbols).

Answer (score 7):

It's colorless.

> 202.2. An object is the color or colors of the mana symbols in its mana cost, regardless of the color of its frame.

> 202.2b Objects with no colored mana symbols in their mana costs are colorless.

> 202.2e An object may have a color indicator printed to the left of the type line. That object is each color denoted by that color indicator. (See rule 204.)

> 202.2f Effects may change an object’s color, give a color to a colorless object, or make a colored object become colorless; see rule 105.3.

The land-become-creature has no mana symbols in its mana cost, it has no color indicator, and no continuous effect sets its color, so it is colorless. Just like it was before becoming a creature.

---

As previously mentioned, there are no token involved. A token is a created object that isn't represented by a card. No object is created, some characteristic of the cards have simply changed. Just like when [Giant Growth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Giant%20Growth) is used.

Comment: I think it's an important part of the answer that Nissa doesn't assign a color as well though.

Comment: @Gendolkari, Fixed.